# procedure error ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, ora-00918

Hey can anyone help with this errors:

`9/10 PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement`

This appear when trying to prints out details based on a single parameter. This is the code I have been using

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRINT_ACTOR_QUOTES (ID_actor CHAR)
 AS
 first_name CHAR(30);
 last_name CHAR(30);
 title CHAR(40);
 year NUMBER;
 role CHAR(40);
quote CHAR(255);
CURSOR print_cursor IS
SELECT a.actorID, a.firstname, a.lastname, m.title as title, m.year as year ,  
 r.rolename as role1 , q.quotechar as quote1 FROM movie m, role r, quote q, rolequote  
rq, actor a WHERE
a.actorID = r.actorID AND
m.movieID = r.movieID AND
rq.quoteID = q.quoteID AND
rq.roleID = r.roleID;
BEGIN  
FOR row IN print_cursor LOOP
SELECT AQ.QUOTES, A.FIRSTNAME, A.LASTNAME 
FROM ACTOR_QUOTES AQ, ACTOR A
Where row.actorID = ID_actor;
END LOOP; 
END PRINT_ACTOR_QUOTES ;
/
```

Comment: Please suggest what you are trying to do with this procedure and in cursor loop.

Comment: I want it to print the rows firstname and lastname from actor table and title, year, role and quote from the nested table actor_quotes

Comment: what is relation between ACTOR_QUOTES and ACTOR table. please mention the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the relevant error is

> PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

(and not the one you mention in the title of your question).

The problem is the SELECT statement in your FOR loop. In PL/SQL, you cannot just select data without doing anything with it. So you need an INTO statement to store the retrieved data in a PL/SQL variable:

```
SELECT AQ.QUOTES, A.FIRSTNAME, A.LASTNAME
  INTO quote, first_name, last_name
FROM ACTOR_QUOTES AQ, ACTOR A
Where row.actorID = ID_actor;
```

Then I can spot several additional problems:

- The SELECT statement seems to be a full outer join which is rarely what you want.
- The SELECT statement with the INTO clause will fail if it returns more than one row.
- What's the purpose of the FOR loop if you overwrite the local variables on each iteration and don't do anything with them.

Comment: joining condition is missing for ACTOR_QUOTES , ACTOR tables in this statement.

Comment: I now have errors PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got myusername.aq_nt

Comment: On what line do you get the error? Possibly it's the comparison between `ID_actor` (a CHAR type) and `row.actorID` (a numeric type?).